# Top-aligning two wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a window i WPF. From this window I can open another window. When I do, I would like it to be "top-aligned" with the parent window, and slightly to the right of it. I.e. something like this:
[image: aligned]

I have put the following in my code for opening the window, which I thought would work.

```
gw.Top = Top;
gw.Left = Left + Width + 10;
gw.Show();
```

The thing is that it doesn't. What I get is this:

[image: unaligned]

Can anyone tell me why this is?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, so I found the source of it. Why it is the source, I don't know. If anyone knows, I would be very happy about an explanation.:) The error occurred because the main window had `ResizeMode="NoResize"`, whereas the "Graph window" didn't.

Comment: Strange, the windows come out perfectly aligned for me.  Windows 7 64, .NET 4.5.1, 1280x800.

Comment: Perhaps you doing something in that "Graph window"? Could you show xaml of first and second window please?

Comment: I have to agree with Sinatr on this one.  Maybe you have `WindowStartupLocation` set?

Comment: Did you try setting the Xaml of both to SnapsToDevicePixels="True" and making real sure that the first window's top is rounded up to an integer?

Comment: I have made an update to the question. If anyone can tell me what the issue is, it will be much appreciated.:)